# Check if item have underscore then create a sub-menu using javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm a new javascript programer and i want to write a script which can create a dropdown menu automatic with underscore before the text from this:

```
<ul class='prime-nav'>
 <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-1'>Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li> <!-- Underscored item -->
 <li><a href='/item-2'>Item2</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-3'>Item3</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-4'>Item4</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li> <!-- Underscored item -->
</ul>
```

Then using javascript to check the item if it has underscore then create dropdown like this

```
<ul class='prime-nav'>
 <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-1'>Item1</a>
 <ul class='sub-nav'>
  <li><a href='/item-1-1'>Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-2'>Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-3'>Sub-Item 3</a></li> <!-- Underscore remove -->
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href='/item-2'>Item2</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-3'>Item3</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-1'>Item4</a>
 <ul class='sub-nav'>
  <li><a href='/item-4-1'>Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-2'>Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-3'>Sub-Item 3</a></li> <!-- Underscore remove -->
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And i have try something like this

```
function underScored(){
  var a = document.querySelector(".prime-nav"),
      b = document.querySelectorAll(".prime-nav>li"),
      d = document.createElement("ul");
  for(var i = 0 ; i < b.length; i++){
    var e = b[i].querySelector("a");
    if(e.textContent.indexOf("_")>-1){
      d.appendChild(b[i])
    }
    b[i].appendChild(d)
  }
}
underScored()
```

and it's only group a first item in the list

Comment: What have you tried? Here, we help you making your code work, not writing it for you. You have to write some code, get stuck, and then come for help.

Comment: Thanks for your response , i will edit this post

Comment: By the way, how do you determine which sub-elements you group together? They must have the same root in the `href`? Like, let's group `/item-4-*`?

Comment: I tried but it's group all the item has underscore

Comment: You still need to show us what you tried.

Comment: If you group all the items that have underscore, you'll get just one group, not one group for `/item-1-*` and one group for `/item-4-*`. Your definition is not very strict. Please specify properly what you expect.

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using Javascript [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/m28wbcyf/57/)

```js
var dom = "";
var next = false;
var selected = document.querySelectorAll('.prime-nav li'); 
var len = selected.length - 1;

selected.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  var text = elem.innerText;
  if (text.startsWith('_')) {
   elem = elem.outerHTML.replace('>_', '>');
    var prepend = "";
    if (!next)
      prepend = "<ul class='sub-nav'>";
    dom += prepend+elem;
    next = true;
  } else {
    if (next)
      dom += "</ul>";
    dom += elem.outerHTML;
    next = false;
  }
  if (next & index == len) {
    dom += "</ul>";
  }

});
document.getElementsByClassName("prime-nav")[0].innerHTML = dom;
```

```html
<ul class='prime-nav'>
  <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1'>Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-2'>Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-3'>Item3</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1'>Item4</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

## Using Jquery

Here is how I did [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m28wbcyf/36/):

```js
var dom = "";
var next = false;
var len = $('.prime-nav li a').length - 1;
$('.prime-nav li a').each(function(index) {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var _li = $(this).parents('li');
  if (text.startsWith('_')) {
    $(this).text(text.replace('_', ''));
    var prepend = "";
    if (!next)
      prepend = "<ul class='sub-nav'>";
    dom += prepend + _li[0].outerHTML
    _li.remove();
    next = true;
  } else {
    if (next)
      dom += "</ul>";
    dom += _li[0].outerHTML;
    next = false;
  }
  if (next & index == len) {
    dom += "</ul>";
  }

});
$('.prime-nav').html(dom);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='prime-nav'>
  <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1'>Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-2'>Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-3'>Item3</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1'>Item4</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's what i am looking for, thanks you so much, i just a new javascript you know. thanks you anyway

Comment: Rajan can you move the sub-menu inside the <li> tag ?

Comment: Of course, I can, but can't you! Next time try your self :) Here is what you need. [Fiddle updated answer](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/m28wbcyf/61/) and Please Upvote my answer

Comment: Ok i'll try myself next time

Comment: You find the updated answer right, [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/m28wbcyf/61/)

Answer (score 1):

What you did is quite weird. I think you should take some time to give some good names to your variable. Letters are not very good to understand what you are handling.

Then, try to understand each line of your code, what did you exactly do.

Here is a solution for your problem, I hope it'll help you:

```js
const underScored = () => {
  const lis = [];
  
  // Let's store HTML elements in an array to use them easier later.
  for(const item of document.querySelectorAll('li')) {lis.push(item);}
  
  // First, let's build groups of items.
  const groupsOfUnderscoreItem = lis.filter(li => li.textContent.startsWith('_')).reduce((acc, item) => {
    const href = item.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
    const root = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('-'));
    acc[root] = acc[root] || [];
    acc[root].push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  // Then, let's perform the modifications to the HTML DOM.
  Object.keys(groupsOfUnderscoreItem).forEach(group => {
    const newList = document.createElement("ul");
    newList.classList.add('sub-nav');
    const rootElt = document.querySelector(`a[href='${group}']`);
    groupsOfUnderscoreItem[group].forEach(li => {
      newList.appendChild(li);
      const a = li.querySelector('a');
      a.textContent = a.textContent.substring(1);
    });
    rootElt.parentNode.appendChild(newList);
  });
};

underScored();
```

```html
<ul class='prime-nav'>
 <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-1'>Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-1-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li> <!-- Underscored item -->
 <li><a href='/item-2'>Item2</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-3'>Item3</a></li>
 <li><a href='/item-4'>Item4</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-1'>_Sub-Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-2'>_Sub-Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/item-4-3'>_Sub-Item 3</a></li> <!-- Underscored item -->
</ul>
```

Comment: but your resolution the dropdown menu item does not have link href :v

Comment: :o, i'll check, i got them before but must have broken it recently.

Comment: @ĐứcTrần fixed!

Comment: can you move the sub nav element inside the <li> tag ? i need to make a dropdown :v

Comment: can you move the sub nav insite the father <li> element ?

Comment: Yep sure. That's actually easier.

Comment: It is adjusted!

Comment: How ? I have no ideas, can you help me this

Comment: I mean like this <li><a></a><ul class='sub-nav'></ul></li>

Comment: Not inside the <a> tag

Comment: Do you have facebook, i have alot of question about this so can you add friend me on fb